# Splitting a string into an array of strings in c#, without using split method?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops, split

Homework question here. Input has be a date, and must be formatted like this: day/month/year (e.g "22/03/2022). Have to come up with a way to split the initial string into an array of three substrings (e.g {"22", "03", "2022"}) using the '/' as a separator. Can't use string.split method.
My initial guess was:

- Build a for loop which cycles through every character of the input string.
- Setting a condition (if char at that loop iteration is NOT equal to separator, include it in a new array).

Doing so however, output would be  {'2', '2', '0', '3', '2', '0', '2', '2'}, that is not what i want.

```
string input = "22/03/2022";
        char separator = '/';
        string[] arr = new string[3];
        int i = 0;
       
        
        for (i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            
            if (input[i] != separator)
            {
                //???
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the assignment asking you to format a date and in order to accomplish that you now _think_ that you need to make your own string-split function, ...or is the assignment _explicitly_ asking you to implement your own string-split function?

Comment: `IndexOf` and `SubString`? Are you actually being asked to split the string, or are you being asked to extract the date components?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Better idea: `ReadOnlySpan<Char>` - gotta keep those GC allocations down :)

Comment: I don't want to give you the exact answer (because this is homework) but here's a suggestion: Have an `int startIndex` variable which you initialise to 0, and an `int currentIndex` which you initialise to 1. Then keep incrementing `currentIndex` until you find a separator, then output the characters between `startIndex` and `currentIndex - 1`. Then set `startIndex` to `currentIndex + 1` and continue looping. You'd have to handle the end of string etc, but hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: You can also keep a count of the number of separators you've seen, and do `arr[numSeparatorsSeen] += input[i]`.

Comment: If it *must* be formatted like this, and that format is not variable, the assignment is very simple, because you know you need the first two characters, then characters 3 and 4 (counting from 0), then characters 6 through 9. This can be made robust with an initial check that the string indeed looks this way. This demonstrates the importance of specifications, because of course that's very different from splitting arbitrary-length strings on arbitrary separators.

Comment: @Dai Yep, assignment is asking to implement my own string-split function, and to accomplish it using a loop of some sort.